# Pass a variable through the url bar with PHP to a form

Tags: php, forms

I need to pass a variable to my other page through the URL bar. I have one error: Notice: `Undefined index: $id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kyle_Site\Programming Rite\controle\delete.php on line 3`

I assume that I'm getting this error from not passing correctly, but I'm not sure any help is appreciated!

I'm passing the variable here:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $username['id'] ; ?>">Delete</a></td>
```

Here is where the variable supposed to be passed:

```
<?php 
require 'core.inc.php';
$id = $_GET['$id'];
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $answer = $_POST['decision'];
    if ($answer == 'yes') {
    echo 'user deleted'; }
} 
echo '<h1>Are you sure you want to delete '.$id.'?</h1>
<form name ="form1" method ="POST" action ="delete.php">
<input type="radio" name="decision" value="yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="decision" value="no">No
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
</form>'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your get Variable is wrong. You should also check if the get variable is set.

```
<?php 
require 'core.inc.php';
if (isset($_GET['id'])
{
$id = $_GET['id']
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $answer = $_POST['decision'];
    if ($answer == 'yes') {
    echo 'user deleted'; }
} 
echo '<h1>Are you sure you want to delete '.$id.'?</h1>
<form name ="form1" method ="POST" action ="delete.php">
<input type="radio" name="decision" value="yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="decision" value="no">No
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
</form>';
}
```

Comment: thanks it works great now XD it's been a long day

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
$id = $_GET['$id'];
```

by

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `$_GET['id']`. No `$` needed.

Comment: should be comment ,,, not expected kind of answer from man who have **Legendary badge** ...come on you are high rep man

Comment: What kind of more involved answer can I give? Any additional word would just be filler text. :)

Answer (score 0):

this is NOT an ‘Error’, but a ‘Notice’. A notice can be ignored if it’s not critical while an error must be fixed. my advice is Check your $id and isset() whether it is null or not. if one of it is null this notice will occur.

Comment: ill never ignore the notice ... ignoring notice ,warning will produce buggy code